# How to generate application error in service using Restangular?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm using AngularJS and Restangular to access an API. I have a service that wraps my API calls. In my service functions, I want to handle both Restangular native errors and application-logic errors. Should I wrap my Restangular promise in a $q deferred layer ?

How can my error generated in (1) be caught and displayed in (2) ?

My service looks like this :

```
    app.service("project", function(Restangular) {
      var projectObj = {
        list : function() {
           ...
           return 0; 
        }, 
        generate : function() {
          var list = projectObj.list();
          if (list == 0) {
            throw 'Empty list returned'; // (1)
          }
          else {
            var promise = Restangular.one('project').get().then( function( returnedProject) {
              console.log("returned", returnedProject);
            }, function() {
              console.log('there was an error'); 
            };
            return promise; 
          }
        } 
    };
  return projectObj;
}
```

The controler using the service:

```
var projectViewCtrl = function ($scope, project, notify) {
  openGenerate = function() {
    $scope.project.generate().then( function( result) {
      console.log('OK');
    }, function (error) {
      notify(error); // (2)
    });
  }
}
projectViewCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope', 'project', 'notify'];
app.controller('projectViewCtrl', projectViewCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to add to your services! I think what you're looking for is an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). You can intercept all of your calls and do logging without adding code to all of your services. Here's an example that redirects users on a `401` response, otherwise logs to the console:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('errorInterceptor', function ($q, $injector) {

    return {
      responseError: function(res) {
        if(res.status === 401) {
          $injector.get('$state').go('login');
        } else {
          console.log(res);
        }
        return $q.reject(r);
      }
    };
  });
```

You also need to register the interceptor in your [app.config](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
```

Comment: Thanks that sounds very handy for Restangular errors. From that example how could I throw an error (to be caught be the interceptor) that is not started by Restangular ? As in my example I test if the response for a (synchronous) function comes back as 0. If it does I want to have an error.